# Elm lang redirect to external URL

Tags: redirect, elm

How can I redirect to external url? I've tried with `Navigation` module, but it seems to work only for local routes. Is there a way to do it natively, without js ports?

I.e. `window.location.href = http://google.com;`

Edit: I somehow missed `Navigation.load` function. As suggested below, it will help with redirects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `a` tag can be always used with specified `href`, I'd rather try to find a solution which would avoid using redirection from `update` function.

```
a [ href "http://google.com" ] [ text "Google link" ]
```

But in case it's necessary to implement the logic similar to `window.location.href = "http://google.com";`, `elm-lang/navigation` provides [load](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/2.1.0/Navigation#load) function (and a couple of other useful ones for forcing page loads) which does, what you're expecting.

It takes a url and returns a command `load : String -> Cmd msg`, so it's going to look like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        RedirectToGoogle ->
            ( model, load "http://google.com" )
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to redirect once the back-end completes the task, so tag is not suitable. But Navigation.load did the job! I somehow missed it :( Have a nice day!